# 18.04 can only resume from suspend by pressing power button

Tags: 18.04, suspend, laptop, lid

I'm having issues resuming my laptop from suspend running Ubuntu 18.04. I can put the laptop into suspend in 3 ways: by pressing the power button, by running the "suspend" command from search, or by closing the laptop lid. However, the only way I seem to be able to resume from suspend is by pressing the power button. Opening the laptop lid won't do anything, nor will pressing the keyboard or using the touch-pad.

I am aware there are multiple similar questions but I've followed them to no avail.

I have gnome-tweaks installed and "Suspend when laptop lid is closed" set to ON.

Things I've tried:

Modifying the values found in `/sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/wakeup` to enabled

Modifying the file found in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` to change the lines

```
HandleSuspendKey=suspend
HandleHibernateKey=suspend
HandleLidSwitch=suspend
HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=suspend
HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend
```

Running `systemctl status systemd-login` after closing the lid and resuming by pressing the power button outputs

```
Apr 06 22:05:33 SAMPSON systemd-logind[1109]: Lid closed.
Apr 06 22:05:33 SAMPSON systemd-logind[1109]: Suspending...
Apr 06 22:06:42 SAMPSON systemd-logind[1109]: Lid opened.
Apr 06 22:06:42 SAMPSON systemd-logind[1109]: Operation 'sleep' finished.
```

This is odd as it seems to indicate the lid open functionality is causing the laptop to wake from suspend which it is not doing.

It might be worth noting I'm running a dual-boot setup with Windows 10 on the other partition. Laptop lid functionality is working fine on that side of things.